# When switching page timer adds too much seconds

Tags: c#, wpf

When I switch page to another and go back my timer starts to count 2 seconds instead of 1.

```
public partial class Page2 : Page
{

    static System.Timers.Timer timer;
    public static int m_counter = 0;
    static int minuty = 0;
    static int started = 0;
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); ;
        czaso.Text = $"{minuty}:{m_counter:00}";
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        if (started == 1)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }


    }
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        czaso.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (m_counter > 59)
            {
                minuty += 1;
                m_counter = 0;
            }
            m_counter++;
            czaso.Text = $"{minuty}:{m_counter:00}";
            if (m_counter == 95)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        });
    }

    private void LpmCzas(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        started = 1;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

I think problem is with timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed; but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Why are your fields all `static`?

Comment: If I remove static from m_counter then after switching page and going back m_counter goes back to 0.

Comment: I put together a proof of concept, works round the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got two instances, both updating the same m_conter. Navigate again and you'll probably have 3.

In theory, you should be able to set your page KeepAlive="true" and it is retained.

Having tried that, doesn't seem to work as msdn says.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

You can instead retain a reference to each page you instantiate.

I tried this with some fairly quick and dirty code as a proof of concept.

My mainwindow:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Page 1"
                Click="Button_Click"
                />
        <Button Content="Page 2"
                Click="Button_Click_1"
                />
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
           Grid.Column="1" Name="fr">
        
    </Frame>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind for that:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateAndCache(Pages[0]);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateAndCache(Pages[1]);
    }

    private void NavigateAndCache(PageItem pageItem)
    {
        if (pageItem.PageInstance == null)
        {
            pageItem.PageInstance = (Page?)Activator.CreateInstance(pageItem.PageType);
        }
        fr.Content = pageItem.PageInstance;
    }
```

The above instantiates a page 1 or page 2 depending on which button you click. If there's already a page cached then it returns that instead of instantiating a new one.

Page1

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    public int m_counter = 0;
    int minuty = 0;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed; ;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            if (m_counter > 59)
            {
                minuty += 1;
                m_counter = 0;
            }
            m_counter++;
            tb.Text = $"{minuty}:{m_counter:00}";
        });
    }
}
```

There's nothing in page 2.

When I try this, the timer is ticking up one a second as expected.

It's pretty rough but doesn't double the number added each ticks.

You will need to pass some sort of shared navigation mechanism into the pages which does the caching and instantiation.

Comment: I removed statics and added  KeepAlive="True" to .xaml and when I navigate back to page with time it starts counting from 0:00.

Comment: I also have issue that when I m_counter == 15 and I want it to navigate to another page automaticly error occurs: System.NullReferenceException: „Object reference not set to an instance of an object.” in NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); line